# missing dependencies in jboss 7.1 while deployment

Tags: jboss7.x

I am running jboss 7.1 in domain mode
 i have created a server namely nodeOne in main-server-group. kept auto-start as true,  port-offset as 800 and jvm is default jvm.
server got created successfully and shown in running state when checked on console.however when I tried to deploy a war file on this server group, deployment failed. please find below error logs to further understand the issue.

```
2018-03-02 15:12:54,359 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0026: JBoss EAP 7.1.0.GA (WildFly Core 3.0.10.Final-redhat-1) started (with errors) in 28900ms - Started 232 of 561 services (47 services failed or missing dependencies, 358 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
2018-03-02 15:54:28,825 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "kau.adjxrs.11.war" (runtime-name: "kau.adjxrs.11.war")
2018-03-02 15:54:32,177 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 16) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "kau.adjxrs.11.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0288: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {
    "Services that were unable to start:" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"kau.adjxrs.11.war\".PARSE"],
    "Services that may be the cause:" => [
        "jboss.http-upgrade-registry.default",
        "org.wildfly.network.interface.public"
    ]
}}
2018-03-02 15:54:32,181 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 16) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "kau.adjxrs.11.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{"WFLYCTL0288: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {
    "Services that were unable to start:" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"kau.adjxrs.11.war\".PARSE"],
    "Services that may be the cause:" => [
        "jboss.http-upgrade-registry.default",
        "org.wildfly.network.interface.public"
    ]
}}
2018-03-02 15:54:32,242 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment kau.adjxrs.11.war (runtime-name: kau.adjxrs.11.war) in 59ms
```

please help me understanding how to address this issue.

Comment: i know I am late but I want to know, Is your problem resolved ?

Comment: No I am still waiting on this issue

Comment: is it Jboss eap or jboss as ?

Comment: share your start-up script and let me know which hosts files you are using for your domain ?

Comment: It was jboss eap.. Will share the startup files in next few hours

Comment: was this ever resolved?